# Pandas replace values in columns based on condtion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
dummy_df_dict  = {'Email':['joblogs@gmail.com', 'joblogs@gmail.com', 'johnsmith@gmail.com', 'johnsmith@gmail.com'],
              'Transaction_Country': ['CA', 'No Country Listed', 'No Country Listed', 'DE'],
             'Country_name': ['Canada', 'No Country Listed', 'No Country Listed', 'Germany'],
                       'Continent':['North America', 'No Contient listed', 'No Contient listed', 'Europe']}
```

```
    Email   Transaction_Country Country_name    Continent
0   joblogs@gmail.com   CA  Canada  North America
1   joblogs@gmail.com   No Country Listed   No Country Listed   No Contient listed
2   johnsmith@gmail.com No Country Listed   No Country Listed   No Contient listed
3   johnsmith@gmail.com DE  Germany Europe
```

I'm just trying to replace the "No "XYZ" listed text with the actual country / continent based on the email above / below.

So for example, the 2nd row [1] instead of showing 'Transaction_Country' as 'No Country Listed' it instead would be replaced with the value 'CA'. And then on the next row, for johnsmith it would be replaced with "DE".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.replace('No Country Listed', np.nan).replace('No Contient listed', np.nan)
df = df.sort_values(['Email', 'Transaction_Country']).groupby('Email')[df.columns].ffill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Email Transaction_Country Country_name      Continent
0    joblogs@gmail.com                  CA       Canada  North America
1    joblogs@gmail.com                  CA       Canada  North America
3  johnsmith@gmail.com                  DE      Germany         Europe
2  johnsmith@gmail.com                  DE      Germany         Europe
```

Looking at it again, I think just this works as well:

```
df = df.replace('No Country Listed', np.nan).replace('No Contient listed', np.nan)
df = df.sort_values(['Email', 'Transaction_Country']).ffill()
```

Comment: @Cummins070 I realized the `groupby` probably isn't necessary if we're already taking the time to sort~

Comment: Nice solution! And well noted, in fact using `groupby` is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.Series.ffill` to propagate last country forward:

```
mask = df["Transaction_Country"].eq("No Country Listed")
df.loc[mask, "Transaction_Country"] = np.nan
df["Transaction_Country"].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the first row, but then the issue is it forward fills row 2 with "CA" when it should be "DE". I guess maybe I could use this in a for loop and first check with the value is NaN, then use ffill or bfill accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion through, I'll see where I can get to with this. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it, I'm just too rusty to figure it out ;P

Answer (score 0):

You fill the 'No Country Listed' and 'No Contient listed' values with NaN using `DataFrame.mask` and then fill the missing values with the first valid country and continent by e-mail.

```
masked_missing = df.mask(df.isin(['No Country Listed', 'No Contient listed']))

res = masked_missing.fillna(masked_missing.groupby('Email').transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
>>> res 

                 Email Transaction_Country Country_name      Continent
0    joblogs@gmail.com                  CA       Canada  North America
1    joblogs@gmail.com                  CA       Canada  North America
2  johnsmith@gmail.com                  DE      Germany         Europe
3  johnsmith@gmail.com                  DE      Germany         Europe
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Email':['joblogs@gmail.com', 'joblogs@gmail.com', 'johnsmith@gmail.com', 'johnsmith@gmail.com'],
    'Transaction_Country': ['CA', 'No Country Listed', 'No Country Listed', 'DE'],
    'Country_name': ['Canada', 'No Country Listed', 'No Country Listed', 'Germany'],
    'Continent':['North America', 'No Contient listed', 'No Contient listed', 'Europe']
})
```